# javascript with html forms getting values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im trying to get text from a product table in order to sAVE them to a shopping cart and put them into a database at a later date.I also want a confirm alert box to appear for the user to confirm before it gets written to a database table. However im having trouble getting the java script to read my html, as i only need to read the fields that have had the drop down list selected.

Any help or guidance would be great!!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction()   
        {
alert(document.getElementById("musicStore").rows[0,1,2,3,4].cells.namedItem(number1,+            "price",+ "album",+ "type").innerHTML);
}
</script>

<form name= "musicStore" Action="" Method="get">
<tr>
    <th>Artist</td>
    <th>Title</td>
    <th>Duration</td>
    <th>Price</td>
    <th>Album</td>
    <th>Format</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rocking eddie</td>
    <td>Song never leaves</td>
    <td>04:34</td>
    <td id="price" value="8.99">£8.99</td>
   <td id="album" value="freshprince">Fresh Prince</td>
   <td><select name="format" id="type">
   <option value=""></option>
    <option value="cd">CD</option>
    <option value="digital">Download</option>
    </select>
   </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Rocking eddie</td>
    <td>Go Home</td>
    <td>06:24</td>
    <td id="price" value="10.99">£10.99</td>
   <td id="album" value="Coffee">Coffee</td>
   <td><select name="format" id="type">
   <option value=""></option>
    <option value="cd">CD</option>
    <option value="digital">Download</option>
    </select>
   </td>
</tr>

<div style ="float: right";>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You have multiple elements with the same ID. For example you have 2 elements with id='type'. ID's are supposed to be unique and won't function properly if there are repeats.
   Use class instead:

   ```
   <td class="price" value="8.99">£8.99</td>
   ```
2. Your javascript code isn't going to loop through properly.
3. You can't use innerHTML in all of your instances because the 'type' is select list. You'd have to get the *value* of that element as opposed to the innerHTML.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27Mh3/) of the working code.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the 2nd to this: `<select name="format" id="type2">`

Something different.

I think you then want:

```
document.querySelector('#type').value
document.querySelector('#type2').value
```